# Why does the address of the assigned object not change in C++?

Tags: c++, class, memory-address, assignment-operator, copy-assignment

In this C++ example, a class `C` has a default constructor, a copy constructor and an assignment operator:

```
struct C {
    C();
    C(const C& c);
    C& operator=(const C& c);
};
```

The implementation is as follows with some output for tracking the objects. I added some example addresses in comments on the lines as reference to the `main` program below.

```
#include "C.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

C::C() {
    cout << "Standard constructor." << endl;
}

C::C(const C& c) {
    cout << "Copy constructor." << endl;
}

C& C::operator=(const C& c) {
    cout << "Address of reference argument: &c = " << &c << endl;      // F9B4
    cout << "Address of this: &*this =           " << &*this << endl;  // F8D4
    return *this;
}
```

I'll be using a factory method that returns anonymous objects:

```
C foo() {
    return C();
}
```

Now in the following program, I create a named object `c` (see (1)) and create an anonymous object (2) which I assign to `c` (3). I expected that `c` then has the address of the anonymous object after the assignment.

```
int main()
{
    C c;  // (1)
    cout << "Address of initial c from main: &c = " << &c << endl;                  // F8D4
    c=foo();  // (2) and (3)
    cout << "Address of initial c from main after assignment: &c = " << &c << endl; // Expected F9B4 but is F8D4
}
```

Comment: `c` is a local variable. Its address will not change.

Comment: Then what does `=` do?

Comment: `=` just copies the internal contents. You cannot change the address of a variable declared on the stack

Comment: A variable is a box with a name; it stores a value inside. `c` is such a box; `foo()` creates and returns an anonymous box. The assignment operator `=` does not affect the boxes, it copies the content from one box to another.

Comment: These comments are worth gold:) I must admit I didn't hope for much when writing this question, but now, expectations exceededè

Comment: I don't think the address of an object can be changed, whether it is allocated on the stack or the free store.

Comment: Worth noting that if you come from C# or Java it's easy to have this confusion.

Comment: `&*this` is just `this` 

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Exactly, that i believe was my difficulty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects in C++ never change addresses.

An assignment operator is no different from any other method, normally it just goes over all member variables and assigns new values to them, copied from the corresponding members of the other object.

Answer (score 5):

The copy assignment operator does not create a new object, It in general changes data members of an already created object. A memory for an object with the automatic or static storage duration is allocated when the object is being created as in this declaration

```
C c;
```

Answer (score 4):

> I expected that c then has the address of the anonymous object after the assignment.

Objects in C++ are allocated on the stack, unless explicitly specified by `new`.

In this case, you're simply creating a temporary anonymous object and then **copying** it on `c`. `c` has the same location on the stack as before.

The reason you might not see the copy constructor message for `c=foo();` is because of something called [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), which is the reason I assume you thought `c` would be holding the anonymous object, and not just a copy of it.